# Looking up data from a row in a single dataframe to create a new column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas, and have been searching for an elegant solution for adding a column to a Pandas dataframe.  I need to look up the '**value**' of a row for a '**Name**', and '**Date**' combination where the '**Denominator**' will match the '**Numerator**'.  It is being used to create ratios for a large stock portfolio which would have roughly 10,000 entries.  In the example below the new column would contain 0.00 for the first value, 345.943 for the second value, and so on.  I have tried numerous approaches I have found here on stackoverflow, but nothing that works in the way I am seeking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Sample Dataframe is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNZA0.png)

Here is the sample data:

```
Numerator                Name                  Date        value    Denominator  
 ------------------     ------------------   ---------    -------  -------------  
60      Revenue         NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-01-01   102.697   Total Assets  
61       Revenue        NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-04-01   114.690   Total Assets  
62       Revenue        NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-07-01   198.267   Total Assets  
63       Revenue        NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-10-01   188.561   Total Assets  
285      Total Assets   NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-01-0     **0.000**        1  
286      Total Assets   NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-04-01    **345.943*       1  
287      Total Assets   NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-07-01      399.08         1  
288      Total Assets   NTNX - Nutanix Inc    2016-10-01      648.263        1
```

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO, have a read of [mcve] and reformat your question with your sample data (as text) and sample output.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the help and it is always a good learning experience when you trip out of the starting gate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any easy way to do that. The only way I've found would be:

```
# Get two copy of dataframe, might have to call .copy here
df_numerator, df_denominator = dataframe, dataframe

df_numerator["key"] = df_numerator["numerator"]
df_denominator["key"] = df_denominator["denominator"]

# This will match the row with same Name, Date and key tuples.
merged_df = df_numerator.join(df_denominator, on=["Name", "Date", "key"]
# Will work provided the length matches
dataframe["new_column"] = merged_df["value"]
```

Comment: Thanks Cal!  I will give it a try and let you know the result.  I have not used the .copy yet.